# Grey out a select option based on xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<Reading>
<Item Time="17:35">
    <SlaveAddress />
    <Slave_4 Value="0" />
    <Slave_3 Value="0" />
    <Slave_2 Value="0" />
    <Slave_1 Value="1" />
</Item>
</Reading>
```

and my dropdownlist look like this

```
<select id="comboBox" style="width:100px;" tabindex="1">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to grey out any of `<select>` `<option>` based on of that XML file? Meaning if `Slave_1`'s value is 1 then the `<option>` 1 is enabled and if `Slave_2` is 0 then `<option>` 2 is then disabled or greyed out.

Then the user can make their choice based on any enabled option.

I would love to have any input from you out there. Javascript or JQuery doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. Parse the xml, mjQueryfy it, the go through it, get the correct stuff out and disable or enable as needed

```
var xml = $.parseXML('your_xml_as_a_string_or_whatever');
var $xml = $(xml);

$xml.find('Item').children().each(function(index, value) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tagName = $this.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
  if (tagName.indexOf("slave_") === 0) {
    var value = $this.attr('Value');
    var number = tagName.slice(-1);
    if (value === '0') {
      $('option[value="'+number+'"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('option[value="'+number+'"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @jakee hey thanks for helping me. I forgot to mention that my xml file is on a C drive, e.g. 'C:/Report'. Would it work on the code you shown here?

Comment: do you have any other suggestion instead to use? Like using a servlet? I'm a beginner so I don't know much yet.

Comment: you might be able to put it in the same folder or something like that and ajax it